# How to escape characters in string in c#

Tags: c#, xml, string

I have this string,and getting an error

string text =

```
<root><Info id="inseID">17</Info><note><123comments></note></root>
```

I wanted to convert it to

```
<root><Info id="inseID">17</Info><note>&lt;123comments&gt;</note></root>
```

Comment: why dont you simply use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: How are you writing it currently? any xml writer, serializer, or DOM API is going to get this right without you having to do anything; if you're building xml by concatenating strings, I'm mostly going to say "don't do that"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please give us more context. Are you really *passed* invalid XML and then have to do something with it? Or do you actually have a string of "<123comments>" that you wish to use as a value in the XML? If you can provide a [mcve] that accurately reflects your situation, that would be very useful.

Comment: There is no escape characters.  Just edit (or added the <123comments> correctly).

Comment: I updated the context, sorry about that. It is an xml, but it was converted to string. If I replace it, it will replace all, is there a way just to replace the value?

Comment: I rolled back the edit - please don't use images for code; I've already fixed the formatting for you

Comment: "is there a way just to replace the value?" - the problem there is: what you have is not valid xml, so you can't use an xml tool to fix it; so that leaves text tools  - and that [doesn't end very well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/23354); ultimately, you need to fix this *before* it gets corrupted

Comment: XML is text. This isn't XML though, it contains malformed parts. How was it created? How do you know that `<123comments>` should be escaped? Why not use `<123comments/>`? The code that produced this text has a bug that needs to be fixed. You can't guess what the correct XML would be, *especially* in this instance.

Comment: yeah it's a long xml, that was passed as a string to replace the `< >`,and then convert it again to `< >`. but the `QA <123 comments> `in note, that breaks the saving in SQL.

Comment: You still need to fix the *producer* code. The answer shows how to do that with LINQ to XML, but the XmlDocument-related classes would also escape text before saving it

Answer (score 1):

Use linq to xml.

```
var text = "<root><Info id=\"inseID\">17</Info><note></note></root>";
var xml = XElement.Parse(text);
xml.Element("note").Add("<123comments>");
//string result = xml.ToString(); // will be escaped
```